# Perform cross validation and best subsets regression on mixed models

Tags: r, mixed-models

I am trying to perform cross validation as part of best subsets regression on mixed models, so far without success. I am looking for help with the following code, or something better.

I found the following working code using the nlme package for generating a fit of every possible model from a pre-defined model, which then calculates and sorts the fitted models by BIC.

```
library(nlme)
fm <- lme(distance ~age*Sex, random = ~ 1|Subject,data=Orthodont,method='ML')
terms <- terms(fm) #store the response and fixed effects
todrop <-  1:length(attr(terms,'term.labels')) #Count # of fixed effects
subs <- unlist(sapply(todrop,function(p) 
  combn(todrop,p,simplify=F)),recursive =F) #Creates list of all combinations of fixed terms
fm.subList <- lapply(subs[-length(subs)],function(s,...){ #Fits each possible model
  newf<- formula(drop.terms(terms(fm),s,keep.response = TRUE)) 
  update(fm,newf)
}) 
names(fm.subList) <- sapply(fm.subList, function(x) paste('fm',attr( 
  terms(x),'term.labels'),sep='.')) 
sort(sapply(fm.subList, BIC))
```

Code was found here: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/best-subset-selection-on-random-effects-model-td4382936.html

However, I'd like to choose the best fitted model with cross validation instead of BIC. I have been trying to use cvFit from the cvTools package, but though I know how to use it separately from the code above, I can't figure out how to combine it with the above code.

Any help with how to combine the two would be appreciated.

Also, as a side note, I have also tried the leaps package and regsubsets combined with cross validation from "Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R," (found here: http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/), but could not figure out how to use mixed models in conjunction with that code (starting p. 249). If I am overlooking something there, I'm also open to suggestions.

Comment: This might be a useful question to follow: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74220/generalized-linear-mixed-models-model-selection

Comment: Will do. Thank you.